# Bypass and coupling capacitors

Tags: decoupling-capacitor, bypass-capacitor

By virtue of the the impedance of a capacitor, can you mathematically  explain how a bypass capacitor filters out high frequency AC noise and how a coupling capacitor filters DC components of a signal or low frequency AC signals?

Comment: This question is asked here every couple of says. There is a bunch of links on the right under the "Related" word. Look there.

Comment: I want a purely mathematical explanation, I can't find enough of those

Comment: One is in series, the other is in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

To model  a regular capacitor the impedance looks like this:

$$ Z = \frac{I}{\omega C}$$

[image]

In the high frequency region parasitics can change the impedance of the capacitor:
[image]

Source: [Murata](http://www.murata.com/products/emiconfun/capacitor/2013/02/14/en-20130214-p1)

In both of these examples the parasitics have no effects in low frequency (ESR lowers the value of the capacitor, but does not change the slope of the impedance line), so the capacitance value holds for low frequencies and you could use just the value or the value of the capacitor and ESR. In most cases this will be a sufficient model for capacitor values and this extends into the low frequency range.

However, one thing we do know is the capacitors have a temperature coefficient that changes the capacitors value with temperature. [Temperature changes](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/5527) are usually low in frequency, from minutes to days. So if your trying to model low frequency effects, if you fix the temperature then the above model still holds. If your trying to build a real world circuit then watch out for temperature changes.

Answer (score 0):

A pc board trace has both inductance and resistance.  If you know the length and cross-section dimensions of the trace, you can calculate its resistance and inductance.  You can calculate the inductor's impedance at any frequency.  These are the series elements of a filter network.  A decoupling capacitor is the shunt leg of the filter.  If you know the capacitor value, you can calculate its impedance at any frequency.  With the resistance, inductive impedance, and capacitive impedance, you can calculate the attenuation at any frequency.